# ASP.NET MVC site examples

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I'm newbie to mvc, do decided to look through some site examples. Started from MVC Music Store from codeplex.
Can pls you give some other links of more and more complex MVC applications?

Comment: Are you looking for examples in production as well or just those that include code? Because this very site http://stackoverflow.com is built on Asp.net MVC.

Comment: I'm looking for source codes. To gather some experience of real applications.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Pro ASP.NET MVC 3 Framework](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1430228865) by Adam Freeman and Steven Sanderson is a great place to start.